# Which alghoritm better for search function?

Tags: android, search, mobile, full-text-search

i am making dictionary app. In my app i am using this codes for search

```
    public void filterValue(String value){

      int size = adapter.getCount();
      for(int i = 0; i<size;i++){
          if (adapter.getItem(i).startsWith(value)){
             dicList.setSelection(i);
            break;
           }

      }
    }
```

But it's not good enogh, it's getting results on top of word list, but i can still see irrelevant words on list. You think is there better version for searching?

There is another version that i used before

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(value);
```

When i use this code, it's listing perfectly (just the words that i wrote to search bar) but when i clicking some result it's directing me another word. For example i am clicking -abc- but it's show me -acc- details.

So any of you have suggestion for this. Thanks.

****edited****

DictionaryFragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DictionaryFragment extends Fragment {

    private int top;
    private int index;
    private FragmentListener listener;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView dicList;
    private Adapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> mSource= new ArrayList<String>();

    public DictionaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dictionary, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        dicList = view.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.kelimelistesi, mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dicList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (listener!=null)
                listener.onItemClick(mSource.get(position));
            }
        });
    }

    //bundan sonra ikinci sözlük olayı başladı
    public void resetDatasource(ArrayList<String> source) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(source);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void filterValue(String value){

   /// adapter.getFilter().filter(value);


     int size = adapter.getCount();
     for(int i = 0; i<size;i++){
         if (adapter.getItem(i).startsWith(value)){
             dicList.setSelection(i);
            break;
          }
      }
    }




    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();  }

        public void setOnFragmentListener(FragmentListener listener){
        this.listener= listener;

        }



}
```

MainActivity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    MenuItem menuSetting;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    DBHelper dbHelper;

    DictionaryFragment dictionaryFragment;
    BookmarkFragment bookmarkFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        dictionaryFragment = new DictionaryFragment();
        bookmarkFragment = BookmarkFragment.getInstance(dbHelper);
        goToFragment(dictionaryFragment, true);

        dictionaryFragment.setOnFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String value) {
                String id =  Global.getState(MainActivity.this,"dict_type");
                int dicType = id == null? R.id.eng_kh:Integer.valueOf(id);
                goToFragment(DetailFragment.getNewInstance(value, dbHelper, dicType), false);
            }
        });
        bookmarkFragment.setOnFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String value) {

                String id =  Global.getState(MainActivity.this,"dict_type");
                int dicType = id == null? R.id.eng_kh:Integer.valueOf(id);
                goToFragment(DetailFragment.getNewInstance(value, dbHelper, dicType), false);
            }
        });

        EditText edit_search  = findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
        edit_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                dictionaryFragment.filterValue(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer;
        drawer = this.<DrawerLayout>findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }



    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        menuSetting = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);

    String id =  Global.getState(this,"dict_type");
    if (id != null)
        onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(Integer.valueOf(id)));

    else {
        ArrayList<String> source =dbHelper.getWord(R.id.eng_kh);
    dictionaryFragment.resetDatasource(source);


    }
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.eng_kh) {
            Global.saveState(this, "dict_type", String.valueOf(id));
            ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(id);
            dictionaryFragment.resetDatasource(source);

            return true;

        } else if (id==R.id.kh_eng){
            Global.saveState(this, "dict_type", String.valueOf(id));
            ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(id);
            dictionaryFragment.resetDatasource(source);

            return true;

        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_bookmark){

            String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
            if (!activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())){

            goToFragment(bookmarkFragment, false);
            }
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_dict){

            String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
            if (!activeFragment.equals(DictionaryFragment.class.getSimpleName())){

                goToFragment(dictionaryFragment, false);
            }
        }


        if (id == R.id.nav_share){

            String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
            Intent shareintent = new Intent();
            shareintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareBody);
            shareintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  getResources().getString(R.string.apkyolu));
            shareintent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, "Paylaş!!!"));
        }



        if (id == R.id.nav_mail){

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }



        if (id == R.id.nav_rate){

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=PackageName")));

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    ///////////////deneme dict ///////



    ////////////////deneme dict /////////////





    void goToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean isTop){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        if (!isTop)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (activeFragment.equals(DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName())){
            menuSetting.setVisible(false);
            toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        } else if (activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            menuSetting.setVisible(false);
            toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.bookmark));

        }else  {
            menuSetting.setVisible(true);
            toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar.setTitle("");
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Word.java

```
public class Word {

    public String key = "";
    public String value = "";

    public Word (){

    }
    public Word(String key, String value ) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you updating the adapter list? Could you include that code in the question as well?

Comment: I added, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting different items due to inconsistent item position. Item positions change when they are added/removed from the list.

**Filtering code**

`adapter.getFilter().filter(value);`

**setOnItemClickListener**

```
dicList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            if (listener!=null)
               listener.onItemClick(adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
        }
    });
```

Changed from `mSource` to `adapterView`, from there we are retrieving the item on the given clicked position.

Comment: You are the best @Taseer, it works perfect :) Thanks a lot